# Aggregate function not working with paste0 in R

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate-functions

I have a data frame subdist.df that has data for sub districts. I am trying to sum up the values of rows based on a common attribute in the data frame i.e `DISTRICT` column.

The following line of code works

```
hello2 <-aggregate(.~DISTRICT, subdist.df,sum)
```

But this one does not.

```
hello <-aggregate(noquote(paste0(".~","DISTRICT")), subdist.df,sum)
```

I am unable to understand why this is the case. I need to use it in a function wherein `DISTRICT` can be any input from the user as an argument.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: I would advise to use the S3 method for data.frame instead of the formula interface of aggregate. Example with iris: `var <- "Species"; aggregate(iris[setdiff(names(iris), var)], by = list(iris[[var]]), sum)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using iris data.frame as an example:

```
aggregate(.~Species, iris, sum)
     Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1     setosa        250.3       171.4         73.1        12.3
2 versicolor        296.8       138.5        213.0        66.3
3  virginica        329.4       148.7        277.6       101.3
```

The following `paste0` doesn't work, as `noquote` only generate an expression and not a formula as required by `aggregate` function:

```
aggregate(noquote(paste0(".~","Species")), iris, sum)
Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : 
  arguments must have same length
```

Instead, adding `as.formula` before `paste0` would work:

```
aggregate(as.formula(paste0(".~","Species")), iris, sum)

     Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1     setosa        250.3       171.4         73.1        12.3
2 versicolor        296.8       138.5        213.0        66.3
3  virginica        329.4       148.7        277.6       101.3
```